# Count the location of array in Java

Tags: java

Let say i have:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{509,508,507,506,505,504,503};

the output should be: 3
```

> *i need to count from 507 to 504 from 0 to n where n is the end where the 504 is located.
>
> *i am confused about this, i have a little code but it's not what i want.

here's my code:

```
 int[] arr = new int[]{509,508,507,506,505,504,503};
 int d = 504;
 int s = 507;
 int x,y = 0;

 for(x = arr[s]; x < arr[d]; x++){
       y += 1;  
 }
```

Anyone can help me about this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You want to count how many numbers appear between 504 and 507 where 507 is inclusive and 504 is not?

Comment: i need to start counting from 0 to 'N', but counting will start only if 507 is reached and it will stop to count if 504 is reached.
so it will give me a result of 3, but im cunfused about this. thanks.

Comment: what you want to do exactly. do you require sorting and then count.

Comment: What you want to do is unclear to me....Please explain

Comment: no its not about sorting. just start to count from 507 to 504. sorry for unclear problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know that 507 would appear before 504, you can use a boolean variable :

```
boolean count=false;
int y=0;
for (int x : arr) {
    if (x == 507)
        count = true;
    else if (x == 504)
        count = false;
    if (count)
        y++;
}
System.out.println(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that returns the index-distance between two values in an array
or -1 if any of them is not present.

```
public static int getDistance(int[] arr, int d, int s) {
       int indexD = -1; int indexS = -1;

       for (int i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
           if (arr[i] == d) indexD = i;
           else if (arr[i] == s) indexS = i;

           if (indexD != -1 && indexS != -1)
               break;
       }
       if (indexD == -1 || indexS == -1) return -1;
       return Math.abs(indexD - indexS);
}
```

*this solution is agnostic regarding sorted or unsorted arrays

*Supposing your array has unique values it works, else it only works for computing the distance between the first appearance of each value.